# Knative service with Keycloak gatekeeper sidecar

Tags: kubernetes, knative-serving

I am trying to deploy the following service:

```
{{- if .Values.knativeDeploy }}
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
{{- if .Values.service.name }}
  name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
{{- else }}
  name: {{ template "fullname" . }}
{{- end }}
  labels:
    chart: "{{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak-gatekeeper:9.0.3
        name: gatekeeper-sidecar
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.keycloak.proxyPort }}
        env:
          - name: KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: {{ template "keycloakclient" . }}
                key: secret
        args:
        - --resources=uri=/*
        - --discovery-url={{ .Values.keycloak.url }}/auth/realms/{{ .Values.keycloak.realm }}
        - --client-id={{ template "keycloakclient" . }}
        - --client-secret=$(KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET)
        - --listen=0.0.0.0:{{ .Values.keycloak.proxyPort }} # listen on all interfaces
        - --enable-logging=true
        - --enable-json-logging=true
        - --upstream-url=http://127.0.0.1:{{ .Values.service.internalPort }} # To connect with the main container's port
        resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.gatekeeper.resources | indent 12 }}
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
        env:
{{- range $pkey, $pval := .Values.env }}
        - name: {{ $pkey }}
          value: {{ quote $pval }}
{{- end }}
        envFrom:
{{ toYaml .Values.envFrom | indent 10 }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: {{ .Values.probePath }}
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          initialDelaySeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.initialDelaySeconds }}
          periodSeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.periodSeconds }}
          successThreshold: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.successThreshold }}
          timeoutSeconds: {{ .Values.livenessProbe.timeoutSeconds }}
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: {{ .Values.probePath }}
            port: {{ .Values.service.internalPort }}
          periodSeconds: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.periodSeconds }}
          successThreshold: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.successThreshold }}
          timeoutSeconds: {{ .Values.readinessProbe.timeoutSeconds }}
        resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {{ .Values.terminationGracePeriodSeconds }}
{{- end }}
```

Which fails with the following error:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "/tmp/helm-template-workdir-290082188/jx/output/namespaces/jx-staging/env/charts/docs/templates/part0-ksvc.yaml": admission webhook "webhook.serving.knative.dev" denied the request: mutation failed: expected exactly one, got both: spec.template.spec.containers'
```

Now, if I read the specs (https://knative.dev/v0.15-docs/serving/getting-started-knative-app/), I can see this example:

```
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1 # Current version of Knative
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helloworld-go # The name of the app
  namespace: default # The namespace the app will use
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/knative-samples/helloworld-go # The URL to the image of the app
          env:
            - name: TARGET # The environment variable printed out by the sample app
              value: "Go Sample v1"
```

Which has exactly the same structure. Now, my questions are:

1. How can I validate my yam without waiting for a deployment? Intellij has a k8n plugin, but I can't find the CRD schema for serving.knative.dev/v1 that are machine consumable. (https://knative.dev/docs/serving/spec/knative-api-specification-1.0/)
2. Is it allowed with knative to have multiple container? (that configuration works perfectly with apiVersion: apps/v1 kind: Deployment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi container is alpha feature in [knative version 0.16](https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/tag/v0.16.0).
This feature need to be enabled by setting `multi-container` to `enabled` in the `config-features` ConfigMap. So edit the configmap using

`kubectl edit cm config-features` and enable that feature.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-features
  namespace: knative-serving
  labels:
    serving.knative.dev/release: devel
  annotations:
    knative.dev/example-checksum: "983ddf13"
data:
  _example: |
    ...
    # Indicates whether multi container support is enabled
    multi-container: "enabled"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Knative are you using?

Support for multiple containers was [added as an alpha feature in 0.16](https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/tag/v0.16.0). If you're not using 0.16 or later or don't have the alpha flag enabled, the request will probably be blocked.

There were a number of edge cases to define for multi-container support in Knative, so the default was to be conservative and only allow one container until the constraints had been explored.